# Force Windows on-screen keyboard to stay up without keyboard or touch-screen?

Tags: windows, on-screen-keyboard

We have Windows 10 kiosks that do not have keyboards or touch screens. Only a mouse. They are running a custom shell, so there is no Windows UI on these.

I am trying to make the on-screen keyboard (osk.exe) stay up, using group policy somehow. Currently, I've added a Scheduled Task via group policy to launch "cmd.exe /c start c:\windows\system32\osk.exe" on login, and every 5 minutes after that.

I am hoping to get something more elegant. For one, the command prompt window flashes every 5 minutes. For two, if the user accidentally closes the on-screen keyboard, they're just gonna have to wait for the next time the task runs and opens the keyboard again.

For now this will work, but is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be achieved with an AutoHotKey script. The script runs and waits for an application to be closed, if closed it re-opens it.

Have it do something like this:

```
#persistent
Process, WaitClose, osk.exe
Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\osk.exe
```

My AHK syntax is a little rusty, so if the code above doesn't work it probably just needs a tweak. Lots of helpful folks here as well as the [AutoHotKey Forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/)